# Homotopy functions

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm new here. Can anyone give me a hint in this problem? Please.  Let $X$ be a topological space. If $f,g$ are continuous function of $f,g\colon X\to S^n$  which $f(x)\neq -g(x)$ for all $x$ in $X$, show $f$ and $g$ are homotopics.
I try to show a homotopy using $$q(x) = \frac{f(x)+g(x)}{\|f(x)+g(x)\|}$$ it's well defined, but i'm stuck.

Comment: Welcome. Please consider having a look around at MathJaX tutorials so your question can be formatted and easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're thinking on the following function as a candidate for homotopy
$$
\begin{align*}
q&\colon X\times I\to S^n\\
(x,t)&\mapsto\frac{tf(x)+(1-t)g(x)}{\vert\vert tf(x)+(1-t)g(x)\vert\vert}\quad t\in I=[0,1]\\
q(x,0)&=g(x)\\
q(x,1)&=f(x)\\
\end{align*}
$$
Since $f(x)\ne -g(x)$ we have that the line $tf(x)+(1-t)g(x)$ connecting $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ does not cross the origin so is not null for $t\in[0,1]$ and therefore $q(\cdot,\cdot)$ is well defined and continuous being the composition of two continuous functions.