# Homotopic functions in $n$-sphere

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Can anyone give me a hint in this problem? Please.  Let $X$ be a topological space. If $f,g$ are continuous function of $f,g \colon X\to S^n$  which $f(x)\neq -g(x)$ for all  $x \in X  $, show $f$ and $g$ are homotopics.

Comment: Why did you just repost this question? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2209652/homotopy-functions

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)+g(x)\neq 0$ implies that  $c(t)=tf(x)+(1-t)g(x)\neq 0, t\in [0,1]$. In fact, $c(t)=0$ implies that $tf(x)+(1-t)g(x)=0$ and $-tf(x)=(1-t)g(x)$ taking the norm of the both sides of the last equation, we deduce that $t=1-t, t=1/2$ and $f(x)/2+g(x)/2=0$. Contradiction.

$H(t,x)={{c(t)}\over{\|c(t)\|}}$ is the requested homotopy.